# C++ Pointers and Destructors

Tags: c++11

```
class Dummy
{
public: 
    int* A{};
    int num{};
public:
    Dummy(int num)
    {
        this->num = num;
        A = new int[num];
    }
    ~Dummy()
    {
        delete[] A;
    }
};

Dummy* dummy()
{
    Dummy* d = new Dummy{ 4 };
    d->A[0] = 1;
    d->A[1] = 2;
    d->A[2] = 3;
    d->A[3] = 4;
    return d;
}
int main()
{
  Dummy* ATT = dummy();
}
```

When I tired to run this program This is always showing Expection at destructor and program can't continue further. What's wrong in this Code...

Comment: Your code doesn't trigger the destructor, you just leak the object.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/8hjqWY8q6). Compiles and runs for me without exceptions. To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown.

Comment: ... which does not mean that it is correct :-)

Comment: What is *exactly* the error message that you get? How do you compile the program?

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `new()` and `delete()` which nowadays in C++ should mostly never be used. Please make yourself comfortable with the appropriate pointer classes which handle memory management for you, like [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).